# "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error",

Tags: angular, typescript, http, httpclient, nativescript

I communicate directly with device.

When I put in browser IP

```
http://192.168.12.1/myconfig?pass=1&name=mywifi&passIS=87654321
```

in browser show this message: `config is ok`.

Now, In my project I create a form that input value. In service.ts I create me POST method like below:

```
public createConfiguration(NewConfiguration: Configuration) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/Json');
    let body = NewConfiguration.generateUrlencodedParameters();
    let url =  ('http://192.168.12.1/myconfig?')
    this.httpclient.post(url, body, {
       }).subscribe(d=>{
      console.log('response create newconfiguration', d)

    })
  }
```

This function show error:

```
JS: ERROR {
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "normalizedNames": {},
JS:     "lazyUpdate": null,
JS:     "headers": {}
JS:   },
JS:   "status": 0,
JS:   "statusText": "Unknown Error",
JS:   "url": null,
JS:   "ok": false,
JS:   "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
JS:   "message": "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error",
JS:   "error": {
JS:     "originalStack": "Error: java.io.EOFException\n    at new c (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/vendor.js:1:1217697)\n    at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/vendor.js:1:1083743\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/vendor.js:1:1084864)",
JS:     "zoneAwareStack": "Error: java.io.EOFException\n    at new c (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/vendor.js:1:1217697)\n    at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/vendor.js:1:1083743\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/vendor.js:1:1084864)"
JS:   }
JS: }
```

Message `config is ok` is in body.

Please, have you any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: console body and make sure your query param must be send in correct form.

Comment: I send correct query params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like below :

```js
// in service.ts file

public createConfiguration(NewConfiguration: Configuration) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/Json');
    let body = NewConfiguration.generateUrlencodedParameters();
    let url =  ('http://192.168.12.1/myconfig?')
    this.httpclient.post(url, body, {});  // <-- you need to subscribe in component.ts file
  }
  
  
  //in compoenent.ts file  
  
  public callerMethod(){  //<- method which calls createConfiguration() service
  
  // srvcObj -> your service object name , paylaod -> input you are sending to servoce method
  this.srvcObj.createConfiguration(payload).subscribe((result:any)=>{
  
           console.log('response create newconfiguration', result);
  },
  (error)=>{
     console.log('got error',error);
  }
  );
  
  }
```